# Pagination with template in grails

Tags: grails, pagination

All my data is rendered in template.I want to add pagination on my page.
here if my controller code

```
def addset={
    def set=QuestionSet.findAllByUserId(session.user)
    params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 5, 100)
    def totalset=QuestionSet.countByUserId(session.user)
    def totalsetlist = QuestionSet.list(fetch: [userId: session.user])
    respond totalsetlist , model:[totalsetCount: totalset,set:set]  
}
```

Here is my view

```
<div class="tbody">
<div id="form">
    <g:render template="form" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
                <g:paginate total="${totalsetCount?: 0}" />
 </div>
```

Data rendered into template here is form template

```
<g:each in="${set}">
    <g:formRemote name="editfrom" update="form"
        url="[controller: 'questions', action:'editset']">

        <g:hiddenField name="setid" value="${it.id}" />

        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td">
                <g:textField id="text${it.id}" class="text" name="setname"
                    required="" disabled value="${it.name}" />
            </div>

            <div class="td">
                ${it.totalquestion}
            </div>

            <div class="td">
                <label class="label label-info"> ${it.name}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="td">
                <label id="edit${it.id}" class="edit">Edit</label>
                <g:submitButton id="save${it.id}" class="save" name="save" />
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                <label class="label label-danger">Delete</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:formRemote>
</g:each>
```

Pagination div showed but pagination not worked .I don't know how to solve this.I didn't found any good example of this.Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check parameter offset, and you need to update your query like this one:

```
def totalsetlist = QuestionSet.createCriteria().list{
   order("${params.order ?: 'id'}"
   maxResults(params.max)
   firstResult(params.offset ?: 0)
 }
```

I didn't work with fetch, but I think you can do it by your self